# Where can I find my Panoramio photos?

Tags: google-photos, panoramio

I have linked my Panoramio account to my Google Plus account.  Now that Panoramio no longer exists, those photos were supposed to appear in Album Archive, but those only contain my Picasaweb photos, not my Panoramio photos.  Where can I find my Panoramio photos?

Answer (score 3):

Google site notes that in Nov 2017 they will copy your Panoramio photos to your Google (photo) Archive - if you have linked your Panoramio account with your Google+ account.

[Source](https://www.panoramio.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Could you add a link to the source for the information in your answer?

Comment: [Source](https://www.panoramio.com/)

Answer (score 2):

**Panoramio still exists** (until Nov 2017) and you can still see and download your photos from there (you can no longer upload photos). In Nov 2017 they will move all photos to Google+ users accounts.

[Source](https://www.panoramio.com/)

[My Pics](https://ssl.panoramio.com/user/3247633?photo_page=15)